# An American English idiom for "die of happiness"

Tags: idioms, american-english, phrase-requests

Is there an American English idiom for Russian "die of/from happiness"?

> I thought I would die of happiness when I heard this wonderful song!

Comment: I could die from happiness is perfectly acceptable in English.  If you are looking for an alternative phrase, please specify such.

Comment: The phrase appears to be about 100 years old in English.  The questioner might want to compare the frequency of the two expressions in both English and Russian although I am not sure how large the Russian corpus is at Google's NGRAM Viewer.

Comment: @Doc Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One such expression which is similar is

> I thought I'd died and gone to heaven when ...

This is attested in Macmillan:

> **I thought I'd died and gone to heaven** *spoken*
>   used for emphasizing that you enjoyed something very much
>
> [[Macmillan]](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/heaven#I-thought-I-d-died-and-gone-to-heaven)

and it's been used [in popular culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_I%27d_Died_and_Gone_to_Heaven) too.

It is predicated on the idea that something **that good** cannot possibly occur on earth, but only in heaven.

Comment: Thank you very much! This phrase is just what I am looking for!

Comment: @ezpresso if you like the answer, consider marking it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

The commonest idiom relating to happiness and afterlife that springs to mind is ***in seventh heaven*** meaning a state of extreme happiness or joy. The phrase [originates](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seventh%20heaven) from the concept of the seventh being the highest of heavens in Islamic and Cabalist doctrines.

A related and equally common idiom is *on cloud nine.* If you are not looking for the exact word *death* that is. Then of course there is that phrase *die laughing*, which is not quite the same as happiness though.

Answer (score 3):

"I could die from happiness" is a perfectly acceptable phrase in English - and one that I've heard used.  Most variants thereof would also be acceptable, such as "I thought I would die from happiness", "I felt so happy I could die", etc.